# cross compile Qt5.10.1 Raspberry pi3 B+ stretch

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to cross compile Raspberry pi3 B+; stretch software 2018-06-27 release, using Qt5.10.1, through Linux ubuntu 64bit according to this steps: https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS

For sure I pay attention to this steps: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62216
and even try to edit make space also like this [Error while cross compiling Qt for a raspberry pi3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654778/error-while-cross-compiling-qt-for-a-raspberry-pi3)  on another time.
I tried different arms pi/pi2/pi3/vc4, and even different Qt versions, although I was able to do it with Jessie, However with stretch I cannot get rid of this error;

```
Configure summary:

Building on: linux-g++ (x86_64, CPU features: mmx sse sse2)
Building for: devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++ (arm, CPU features: neon)
Configuration: cross_compile compile_examples enable_new_dtags largefile neon precompile_header shared rpath release c++11 concurrent dbus reduce_exports stl
Build options:
  Mode ................................... release
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Building shared libraries .............. yes
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++11
  Using ccache ........................... no
  Using gold linker ...................... no
  Using new DTAGS ........................ yes
  Using precompiled headers .............. yes
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    NEON ................................. yes
  Build parts ............................ libs
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... yes
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... yes
  QML debugging .......................... yes
  udev ................................... yes
  Using system zlib ...................... yes
Qt Core:
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ yes
  GLib ................................... yes
  iconv .................................. yes
  ICU .................................... no
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  Using system PCRE2 ..................... no
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... yes
  IPv6 ifname ............................ yes
  libproxy ............................... no
  OpenSSL ................................ yes
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ yes
  HarfBuzz ............................... yes
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ yes
  Fontconfig ............................. yes
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. yes
    ICO .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. yes
      Using system libjpeg ............... yes
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ yes
  EGL .................................... no
  OpenVG ................................. no
  OpenGL:
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... no
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ no
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... yes
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. yes
  libinput ............................... yes
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. yes
  tslib .................................. yes
  xkbcommon-evdev ........................ yes
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. no
  LinuxFB ................................ yes
  VNC .................................... yes
  Mir client ............................. no
  X11:
    Using system-provided XCB libraries .. yes
    EGL on X11 ........................... no
    Xinput2 .............................. yes
    XCB XKB .............................. yes
    XLib ................................. yes
    XCB render ........................... yes
    XCB GLX .............................. yes
    XCB Xlib ............................. yes
    Using system-provided xkbcommon ...... no
    Native painting (experimental) ....... yes
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... yes
Qt Sql:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... yes
  PostgreSQL ............................. yes
  SQLite2 ................................ yes
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... yes
Qt SerialBus:
  Socket CAN ............................. yes
  Socket CAN FD .......................... yes
QtXmlPatterns:
  XML schema support ..................... yes
Qt QML:
  QML interpreter ........................ yes
  QML network support .................... yes
Qt Quick:
  Direct3D 12 ............................ no
  AnimatedImage item ..................... yes
  Canvas item ............................ yes
  Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes
  Flipable item .......................... yes
  GridView item .......................... yes
  ListView item .......................... yes
  Path support ........................... yes
  PathView item .......................... yes
  Positioner items ....................... yes
  ShaderEffect item ...................... yes
  Sprite item ............................ yes
Qt Gamepad:
  SDL2 ................................... no
Qt 3D:
  Assimp ................................. yes
  System Assimp .......................... no
  Output Qt3D Job traces ................. no
  Output Qt3D GL traces .................. no
  Use SSE2 instructions .................. no
  Use AVX2 instructions .................. no
  Aspects:
    Render aspect ........................ yes
    Input aspect ......................... yes
    Logic aspect ......................... yes
    Animation aspect ..................... yes
    Extras aspect ........................ yes
Qt 3D GeometryLoaders:
  Autodesk FBX ........................... no
Qt Wayland Drivers:
  EGL .................................... no
  Raspberry Pi ........................... no
  XComposite EGL ......................... no
  XComposite GLX ......................... no
  DRM EGL ................................ no
  libhybris EGL .......................... no
Qt Wayland Client ........................ yes
Qt Wayland Compositor .................... yes
Qt Bluetooth:
  BlueZ .................................. yes
  BlueZ Low Energy ....................... yes
  Linux Crypto API ....................... yes
  WinRT Bluetooth API (desktop & UWP) .... no
Qt Sensors:
  sensorfw ............................... no
Qt Quick Controls 2:
  Styles ................................. Default Fusion Imagine Material Universal
Qt Quick Templates 2:
  Hover support .......................... yes
  Multi-touch support .................... yes
Qt Positioning:
  Gypsy GPS Daemon ....................... no
  WinRT Geolocation API .................. no
Qt Location:
  Geoservice plugins:
    OpenStreetMap ........................ yes
    HERE ................................. yes
    Esri ................................. yes
    Mapbox ............................... yes
    MapboxGL ............................. no
    Itemsoverlay ......................... yes
Qt Multimedia:
  ALSA ................................... yes
  GStreamer 1.0 .......................... yes
  GStreamer 0.10 ......................... no
  Video for Linux ........................ yes
  OpenAL ................................. no
  PulseAudio ............................. yes
  Resource Policy (libresourceqt5) ....... no
  Windows Audio Services ................. no
  DirectShow ............................. no
  Windows Media Foundation ............... no
Qt WebEngine:
  Embedded build ......................... yes
  Pepper Plugins ......................... no
  Printing and PDF ....................... no
  Proprietary Codecs ..................... no
  Spellchecker ........................... yes
  Native Spellchecker .................... no
  WebRTC ................................. no
  Use System Ninja ....................... yes
  Geolocation ............................ yes
  Use v8 snapshot ........................ yes
  Use ALSA ............................... yes
  Use PulseAudio ......................... yes
  Optional system libraries used:
    re2 .................................. no
    icu .................................. no
    libwebp, libwebpmux and libwebpdemux . no
    opus ................................. no
    ffmpeg ............................... no
    libvpx ............................... no
    snappy ............................... no
    libsrtp .............................. no
    glib ................................. yes
    zlib ................................. yes
    minizip .............................. no
    libevent ............................. no
    jsoncpp .............................. no
    protobuf ............................. no
    libxml2 and libxslt .................. yes
    lcms2 ................................ no
    png .................................. yes
    harfbuzz ............................. yes
  Required system libraries:
    fontconfig ........................... yes
    dbus ................................. yes
    nss .................................. no
    khr .................................. yes
    glibc ................................ yes
  Required system libraries for qpa-xcb:
    libdrm ............................... yes
    xcomposite ........................... no
    xcursor .............................. no
    xi ................................... no
    xrandr ............................... no
    xtst ................................. no

Note: Also available for Linux: linux-clang linux-icc

Note: Dropped compiler flags '-pthread' when detecting library 'glib'.

Note: Dropped compiler flags '-pthread' when detecting library 'gstreamer'.

Note: Dropped compiler flags '-pthread' when detecting library 'gstreamer_app'.

ERROR: Feature 'opengles2' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'config.win32 || (!config.watchos && !features.opengl-desktop && libs.opengl_es2)' failed.

ERROR: The OpenGL functionality tests failed!
You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL[_ES2],
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL[_ES2] and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL[_ES2] in the mkspec for your platform.
```

I repeat it several times and searched for 3 weeks without solution, I really hope if some one can help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue

```
sudo ln -fs /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so.2
sudo ln -fs /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so.1
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've missed the flags "**-opengl es2 -eglfs**" when running configure.

Comment: actually the problem was another issue, I will post the answer